# SQL Server Timezone in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing datetime field with UTC time. We have a requirement to filter the records with CST timezone. 
I have tried this query:

```
select id, CreatedOn,
       CreatedOn AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS LocalTime
from Status
WHERE CAST((CreatedOn AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time') AS date) = '2018-09-06'
order by CreatedOn desc;
```

The issue is that it is also bringing those records which were saved on September 5th CST time in the evening when the UTC time was changed to 6th September. What is the correct way to filter out only September 6th records in CST time?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an issue with the query, I was missing 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE in the where clause. Here is the correct query which works:

```
select id, CreatedOn,
       CreatedOn AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AS LocalTime from CosmoStatus WHERE CAST((CreatedOn AT TIME ZONE
'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time') AS date) = '2018-09-06'
order by CreatedOn desc;
```